# server error with GET form django

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error

I am following this tutorial https://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/jquery_django_tutorial/

which works great. Now I tried integrating the instant search function on the same page. My app is running, however when I type a search term in the form nothing happens. In the terminal however, I get this

```
[09/Aug/2015 22:24:16]"GET /search/?cars_search_text=bmw HTTP/1.1" 500 12558
```

in pink, which means a server error. 
The app from the tutorial shows this in white (I know it depends on the status number behind)

```
[10/Aug/2015 05:20:13]"GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=un HTTP/1.1" 200 147
```

So, how do I find out more about the server error or why the search function doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you are right ! It points to the URL with the exact error, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In development, with `DEBUG = True` set in your Django project settings, simply navigate to that page (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?cars_search_text=bmw) in your browser to see the error.

Comment: THANKS ! and the reason for the error was I forgot to import render_to_response